# How to use matplotlib to draw two sets of data at the same grid point on a map

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I have two sets of data that need to be plotted on the same map using different color contours.I created a grid with two sets of elevation data on the same grid grid, but my program could only draw one set of data on the graph, and the second set of data seemed unable to be drawn.How can I draw two sets of contour lines on the same map?
'TPL': an interpolation method
'Maskout.shp2clip': to screen points outside the area of interest. The purpose is to draw contour lines without considering the shielded points.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

m = Basemap(projection='merc', llcrnrlat=2, urcrnrlat=25,
            llcrnrlon=99, urcrnrlon=122, resolution='c')
m.drawcoastlines()
m.fillcontinents(color='grey', lake_color='white')
m.drawparallels(np.arange(0, 30, 5), labels=[1, 1, 0, 1])
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(100, 125, 5), labels=[1, 1, 0, 1])

cx, cy = np.mgrid[99:122:0.5, 2:25:0.5]
ax = plt.gca()  # gca means get current axes, that is to say get the ax object
z1 = np.hsplit(self.shg1 * 100, 3)
z1_1 = z1[1]
cz = self.TPL_interpolation(cx, cy, z1_1)
cx, cy = m(cx, cy)
zf1 = plt.contour(cx, cy, cz, colors='k', linestyles=['--', '--'])
clip1 = maskout.shp2clip(zf1, ax, m, r"E:\世界shp\南海\nanhai_ocean.shp", 'Ocean')
# plt.gca().clabel(clip,inline=True,fmt='%.2f',fontsize=10,colors='black')

z2 = z1[2]
cz2 = self.TPL_interpolation(cx, cy, z2)
cx, cy = m(cx, cy)
cj1 = plt.contour(cx, cy, cz2, colors='red')
clip2 = maskout.shp2clip(cj1, ax, m, r"E:\世界shp\南海\nanhai_ocean.shp", 'Ocean')
# plt.clabel(contour2,inline=True,fmt='%.2f',fontsize=10,colors='red')
plt.show()
```